# Visualization of how K means clustering is used to select K anchor boxes?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cnn, computer-vision, yolo

I was having trouble understanding how K means clustering is used to select K anchor boxes.

We have ground-truth boxes and we run K means clustering on them using IOU as a metric. There is no good graphical explanation on how IOU is used as a metric and how centroids (anchor boxes) shift with IOU.

If anyone could provide me a visualization of How K means clustering works in the context of anchor boxes that would be a huge help.